# Java testing with mockito: mock class object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I would like to mock an object inside my class.

```
public class Controller{

   private StandardEmailSender sender = new StandardEmailSender();

    public void process() throws EmailException {
       // do some stuff
       sender.sendEmail(to, subject, body);
       // do some stuff
    }
 }
```

I would like to mock `sender.sendEmail(to, subject, body);`. I've spent time finding a solution but I'm stuck. I tried to mock directly the object StandardEmailSender like this :

```
@Mock
StandardEmailSender sender;

@Before
public void setUp() throws EmailException {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    doNothing().when(sender).sendEmail(anyString(), anyString(), anyString());
}

@Test
public void test() throws EmailException {
    Controller controller= new Controller ();
    controller.process();

    //make some asserts
}
```

Would someone have a solution to my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices here:

- make it possible for your test case to "manually" inject a (mocked) Sender object (for example by providing a constructor to set that field)
- make use of Mockitos [@InjectMocks](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation

A typical approach for option 1 is to use constructor telescoping, like this:

public class Controller {

```
 private final Sender sender;

 public Controller() { this(new StandardEmailSender()); }
 Controller(Sender sender) { this.sender = sender; }
```

By doing so, clients can still create a Controller instance without worrying about providing a sender, and your unit tests can use that package protected constructor to provide a mocked sender instance.

Comment: @Kagelmacher Yes it does. But some people still dislike it: https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/ ... and in case you find my answer sufficient, please dont forget about accepting at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Use a form of dependency injection, for example:

```
public class Controller{
   private final EmailSender sender;

   Controller(EmailSender emailSender) {
       this.sender = Objects.requireNonNull(emailSender); 
   }

   public Controller() {
      this(new StandardEmailSender());
   }     
}
```

In your test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws EmailException {
    Controller controller= new Controller(mockedSender);
    controller.process();
}
```